# MySQL Matching where clause with optional NULL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables - patients, and issuers.
I with to extract entire patients table along with issuer_name from patients and issuers table. Optionally there might be no issuer of patient identifier.

If i do:
`select * from patients, issuer_name where patients.issuer_of_patient_identifier=issuer.issuer_id` doesn't return anything in case for the corresponding patient table row `issuer_of_patient_identifier` is NULL.

How do i accomplish this?

```
mysql> describe patients;
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field                        | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| patient_id                   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| patient_identifier           | varchar(64)  | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| issuer_of_patient_identifier | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| medical_record_locator       | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| patient_name                 | varchar(128) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| birth_date                   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| deceased_date                | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| gender                       | varchar(16)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| ethnicity                    | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| date_created                 | datetime     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
| last_update_date             | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL              | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| last_updated_by              | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe issuers;
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| issuer_id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| issuer_name      | varchar(64)  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| issuer_uid       | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| issuer_uid_type  | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| date_created     | datetime     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
| last_update_date | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL              | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| last_updated_by  | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Hint: Left join

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Can we do it without join?

Comment: Yes a correlated sub query in select statement but it may be expensive solution

Comment: @kingsmasher1 Your current query actually already is doing a join, just an implicit one.  See the Gordon Linoff answer below for more information.

Comment: `select * from patients, issuer_name where (patients.issuer_of_patient_identifier=issuer.issuer_id OR patients.issuer_of_patient_identifier IS NULL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is

```
select * from patients 
LEFT JOIN issuer_name ON 
patients.issuer_of_patient_identifier = issuer.issuer_id
```

Without joins:

```
select * from patients, issuer_name
where patients.issuer_of_patient_identifier = issuer.issuer_id
OR patients.issuer_of_patient_identifier IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps.

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Avoid tutorials that use commas.  Challenge instructors that show examples with them.

You want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select *
from patients p left join
     issuer_name i
     on p.issuer_of_patient_identifier = i.issuer_id;
```