# MySQL query left join messing things up

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

This query returns 4 rows:

```
SELECT count(*) from 
patients join patient_observations on patients.patient_id=patient_observations.patient_id
join studies on patient_observations.study_id=studies.study_id AND studies.patient_id=patients.patient_id
join series on series.study_id=studies.study_id 
join instances on instances.series_id=series.series_id
join sop_classes on sop_classes.sop_class_id=instances.sop_class_id
join files on files.instance_id=instances.instance_id
join modalities on modalities.modality_id=series.modality_id
AND patient_name LIKE 'DRAGON^DEBBIE%';
```

If i add this extra line, it returns 3923 rows which is wrong:

```
left join issuers on patients.issuer_of_patient_identifier=issuers.issuer_id
```

Wrong in the sense, issuers table has just 121 rows:

```
mysql> select count(*) from issuers;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      121 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The purpose of adding left join was, there might be some patients where `patients.issuer_of_patient_identifier` is `NULL` as if i just do a normal join it returns 0 rows (See this: [MySQL Matching where clause with optional NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196582/mysql-matching-where-clause-with-optional-null))

Please help, so that i can get the correct rows (Only 4)

Comment: Have you tried right join instead of left/inner join?

Comment: Right join won't serve the purpose because there might be patients which doesn't have `issuers` so they would be skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A
------
1 a1
2 a2

B
-------
1 b1 a1
2 b2 a1



left join A and B
----------------------

1 a1 1 b1 a1
1 a1 2 b2 a1
2 a2 null null null
2 a2 null null null
```

Here are 4 rows as expected, and if you count(*) you will get 4 rows. But if you want to know the matching number of rows in table B, you should do count(distinct b.id)

summary:
try `count(distinct issuer.issuer_id)` instead of `count(*)`

**After discussion in chat:**

Actually the big problem was in the filtering clause. The sql should be like below -

```
SELECT count(*) from 
patients join patient_observations on patients.patient_id=patient_observations.patient_id 
join studies on patient_observations.study_id=studies.study_id AND studies.patient_id=patients.patient_id 
join series on series.study_id=studies.study_id 
join instances on instances.series_id=series.series_id 
join sop_classes on sop_classes.sop_class_id=instances.sop_class_id 
join files on files.instance_id=instances.instance_id 
left join modalities on modalities.modality_id=series.modality_id 
left join issuers on (patients.issuer_of_patient_identifier=issuers.issuer_id) 
where patient_name LIKE 'DRAGON^DEBBIE%';
```

Comment: did you do left join?

Comment: So, as from your example, that is the problem. It returns a2 twice.

Comment: Yes, same left join.

Comment: `left join issuers on patients.issuer_of_patient_identifier=issuers.issuer_id` and `SELECT count(distinct issuer_id)`

Comment: seems like you are trying to find unique number of the issuer, can't you just do count(distinct patients.issuer_of_patient_identifier) without event joining with issuers table

Comment: In your example, you are doing a simple left join NOT left join on condition.

Comment: skipped the obvious part actually, that's join on 3rd column of table B

Comment: There might be "n" patients, who have a specific issuer. So i need to match them using a conditional statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155450/discussion-between-safat-and-kingsmasher1).